# Itextsharp refreshing page after creating PDF

Tags: asp.net

I have a aspx page on which i have two buttons(MakePdf and View) on view button a gridview is shown on the page and with makePDF we can download PDF.
But what i need is view button code should be executing after downloading the PDF.
Please provide me a solution.

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 15, 12);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
        document.Open();
        PdfPCell cell;
        Phrase phrase;
        PdfPTable table;


        table = new PdfPTable(1);
        table.SetWidths(new int[] { 10 });
        table.SpacingBefore = 5f;


        phrase = new Phrase();
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("HSE Monthly Report ", TOPTextFont));
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(phrase));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        cell.Border = 0;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        table.CompleteRow();
document.Add(table);
        document.Close();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= SampleExport.pdf");
        Response.End();
```

Comment: How do you providing download to the user ? Show some code

Comment: I have uploaded the code..

Comment: please provide me a solution @Coder of Code

Comment: I don't know if this will work I didn't tested it one way is create the link button for the save and on click of that button open new window and with the same code save the file at users browser while on your already open page trigger the view button call using jquery that way your already open page show the grid and also your newly opened tab will provide download. If you go through this approach please let me know in case of issues.